# fatal error: simplecpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I installed simplecpp codeblocks and started with the hello world program. When I compile the file, it shows this error in the build log "fatal error: simplecpp: No such file or directory". I've searched the reason for error also in google, but found nothing. I've uninstalled and installed the app again three or four times and even referred youtube videos for the same. But the problem still persists. Someone please help me out.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzocX.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure if we have simplecpp header in c++ library. you can remove that line and retry compiling your code. in your case it is line 1.

Comment: @rakesh.sahu I've tried it and it gives the error now as "error: 'main_program' does not name a type". And regarding the header in c++ library, many videos have shown including simplecpp header. The similar program has worked for many of my friends after including the header also.

Comment: from the github for simplecpp (https://github.com/ranadeag/SimpleCPP) I found that code should be compiled using s++.
In image I see it using using mingw32-g++ compiler which seems wrong. You might need to check the compiler settings.

Comment: Please tell us how did you install `simplecpp`; also, what is your operating system; also: are you familiar with `cmake`, `gcc`, command-line, `Makefile`?